# dotnetnuke journal shows duplicate posts when click the more button

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Using DNN 7.0.5 I have the journal module on a page and it works fine until the more button is clicked. The more button seems to show multiple instances of the same post (only one post is in the database). 
Has anyone seen a fix for that or even seen that problem?

UPDATE: This seems to be when I reach the end of the list of journal posts.
For Example: I have read down the list of journal entries and I get the very first one (in the database) and click the show more button again it gives me duplicates of the last items (I will make a video to demonstrate)

Comment: Do you happen to have multiple Journal modules on the page?

Comment: Nope - already checked that